# Can resolution of the Kadison-Singer Problem provide progress on the Komlos Conjecture?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, spectral-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, discrepancy-theory

This is not a concrete question, just some thoughts.
The **Komlos Conjecture** is as follows-

> There exists an absolute constant $C>0$, such that the following holds:
>
> For all $d$ and any set of vectors $v_1,\dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\Vert v_i\Vert_2 = 1$, there exists  signs $\epsilon_i\in \{1,-1\}$ such that $\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i v_i \Vert_\infty \leq C$.

This implies another conjecture from Discrepancy Theory, namely the **Beck Fiala conjecture** (discrepancy of a bounded degree hypergraph). The state of the art result implies that $C = C(n) = O(\sqrt{\log n})$ (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02882.pdf)).

On the other end of the spectrum, the positive resolution of Kadison-Singer (KS) problem by [Interlacing Families II: Mixed Characteristic Polynomials and the Kadison-Singer Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3969)
 is a discrepancy result in disguise. It states that (this formulation is stated [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.06731.pdf))

> For all $d$ and any set of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb{C}^d$ with $\max_{i\in[n]}\Vert v_iv_i^\star\Vert\leq \epsilon$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_iv_i^\star = I$, there exists signs $\epsilon_i\in\{-1,+1\}$ such that $\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_iv_iv_i^\star\Vert\leq O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$.

My query is: Can the ideas leading to the resolution of KS problem be adapted to attack the Komlos conjecture? Has this approach been taken already (I could not find) or is it not a viable approach?

PS: My query is not at all concrete or well formulated. The superficial similarity between the problems do not imply that they should be approached similarly.

Comment: Someone added a tag of extremal combinatorics. I fail to understand how is it related?

Comment: The discrepancy theoretic formulation of Kadison-Singer was given in [this paper of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209078), although Akemann and Anderson had established some connections earlier.

Comment: My feeling is that all of the major problems in discrepancy theory that have been solved, have been solved in completely different ways.  I don't see much chance that the solution to Kadison-Singer will shed much light on Komlos. I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @NikWeaver thanks for the comment.